# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function - ember js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

This is my first attempt with ember js.
I am making a simple form for login. I have created the application using ember-cli.  To keep things short,  This is what I have added to the skeletal app:

This is the app.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import Resolver from 'ember/resolver'; 
import loadInitializers from 'ember/load-initializers';
import config from './config/environment';

Ember.MODEL_FACTORY_INJECTIONS = true;


var App = Ember.Application.create({
modulePrefix: config.modulePrefix,
podModulePrefix: config.podModulePrefix,
Resolver: Resolver
});

loadInitializers(App, config.modulePrefix);

export default App;
```

This is the app/router.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
 import config from './config/environment';

var Router = Ember.Router.extend({
 location: config.locationType
});

export default Router.map(function() {
this.route('login', {path: '/login'});
});
```

This is the template templates/login.hbs:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" {{action "login" bubbles=false}}>

<div class="control-group">
  <div class="control-label">
  <label>Username</label>
</div>
  <div class="controls">
  {{input value=username type="text"}}
  </div>
</div>

 <div class="control-group">
  <div class="control-label">
  <label>Password</label>
</div>

<div class="controls">
  {{input value=password type="password"}}
 </div>
</div>

<button type="submit" class="btn" >Log in!</button>
</form>
```

This is the app/controllers/login_controller.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

var LoginController = Ember.Controller.extend({
 loginFailed: false,
 isProcessing: false,
  actions: {
   login: function() {
    this.setProperties({
    loginFailed: false,
    isProcessing: true
    }); 

  }
 }

});


export default LoginController;
```

It is giving this error in the console:

`Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a functionapp-boot.js:25 (anonymous function)`

If I give some username and password and click on Login! it give this error:

`Uncaught Error: Nothing handled the action 'login'. If you did handle the action, this error can be caused by returning true from an action handler in a controller, causing the action to bubble.`

What am I doing wrong. Plz help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ...

```
var App = Ember.Application.create({
```

... should rather be ...

```
var App = Ember.Application.extend({
```

Thus you should get rid of the `undefined is not a function`.

As for your second problem, I think it's induced by your first problem. At least [in a JsBin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/gijuxojumu/2/edit?html,css,js,output) it works fine.

If the second problem still exists after the first has been solved, just ask again. A working example in a JsBin would be very nice. :-)

Comment: that helped to remove the first error. Regarding the second one i had to rename the controller from login_controller.js to login.js, and update the code accordingly. thanks